# JLabel not showing up at all?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

So this is my 3rd post for this project, hopefully the last.  So when my program does on the math in the other classes, it needs to come out to a JLabel.  the problem is, it doesn't show up.  Maby one of you could help me?
Sorry the code will be f'ed up when I post it, I cant fix it.

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class AFA {

    public void answer() {
        System.out.println("1");
        int area = (int) (AF.length * AF.width);

        String an = String.valueOf(area);

        JFrame answer = new JFrame();

        answer.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
        JLabel a = new JLabel("The answer is " + an + "We got this by multiplying the Lenght by the width");
        pan2.add(a);
        System.out.println("1");
        answer.setVisible(true);            
    }    
}
```

Comment: Oh for pity's sake, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) like I posted as an answer to your last question.  I was going to run the code to see if this is a duplicate of the last question, but could not be bothered turning your code into an SSCCE *again!*

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple GUI not showing up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339398/simple-gui-not-showing-up)

Comment: Same code, different question.

Answer (score 5):

You never added the panel to the frame. Adding the below line should fix this.

```
answer.setContentPane(pan2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the JPanel's `revalidate()` and `repaint()` methods.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint) question might provide more information.